# Hibernate H2 app does not shut down when nothing is left to run

Tags: hibernate, h2

My test project contains only three files: a maven pom file, a Java main file and a persistence.xml file.

POM:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.181</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.6.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.6.Final</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

persistence.xml:

```
<persistence-unit name="TestPU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.h2.Driver"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:h2:file:~/test"/>
    </properties>

</persistence-unit>
```

Main:

```
public class App {
    public static EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("TestPU");
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
        em.getTransaction().begin();
        em.getTransaction().commit();
        em.close();
        System.out.println("complete");
    }
}
```

The application does not shutdown after complete has been printed.

I believe the problem is caused by embedded H2.

How can I get the application to close gracefully after it has finished running?

Comment: Could you get a full thread dump and post it here? To get it, run `jps -l` to get the process id, then `jstack -l <pid>` to get the full thread dump. There has to be a non-daemon thread somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only "problem" is caused by the fact that Hibernate is not being telepathic. The library has no way of knowing what you mean by "application finishes running", as in Java there is nothing special about finishing the main thread. Specifically, application is not finished until any of its threads are still alive. In your case, the application is kept alive by the pool of db connections managed by the EntityManagerFactory.

If you want to finish, just close the pool:

```
emf.close();
```

Comment: That solves the problem and is way better than `System.exit(0);`. You've saved me from code reviewers.